# Android установить divider для RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, divider, recyclerview.adapter

Использую RecyclerView.Adapter, возник вопрос - как установить простой Divider (**Android set divider RecyclerView**)  с возможностью программного изменения цвета и/или толщины для него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я немножко гуглил и немножко эксперементировал и получил самое простое решение из возможных.

1) Для RecyclerView невозможно просто так взять и назначить divider, необходимо присвоить `recyclerView.addItemDecoration()`

2) В связи с чем, я создал класс-наследник RecyclerView.ItemDecoration и реализовал 2 метода - получение высоты и саму отрисовку.

3)

```
public class Divider extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private int mColor;
        private int mHeight; // in px format
        private Paint mPaint;

        public Divider(Context ctx, boolean isDarkTheme) {
            this.mColor = ContextCompat.getColor(ctx,
                    isDarkTheme ? R.color.dark : R.color.light);
            this.mHeight = 1; //1 px
            this.mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(mColor);
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, 
RecyclerView.State state) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mHeight); //высота разделителя
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, 
RecyclerView.State state) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
                canvas.drawRect(view.getLeft(), view.getBottom(), view.getRight(),
                        view.getBottom() + mHeight, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
```

4) Теперь, при создании адаптера, мы указываем класс, который отвечает за отрисовку разделителя:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
new Divider(this,MySystem.getInstance().isDarkTheme());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам съэкономить время, при создании изменяемых разделителей для ваших списков, на основе RecyclerView. Удачи!

Comment: В `Support Library 25.0.0` появился стандартный `DividerItemDecoration ` поэтому использовать нужно его https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html

Comment: Спасибо за расширение ответа, значит моё решение можно использовать на всём, что использует более ранние библиотеки. Например, у меня в текущем проекте используется 23.0.2

Comment: Ну это да. Но лучше обновляйте support library. Все таки гугл правит баги в ней